# Minimising AI usage in a gme

Tags: java, 2d, artificial-intelligence, game-engine, jogl

I have been working on a 2D top down shooter game for a while, I've implemented most of the game and wrote the engine from scratch in JOGL but i ran into a small problem and would like to get other peoples view on how to best approach the problem. So I have creeps spawning at random locations in the map, and each of these creeps use A* path finding, it has been optimized to minimize unnecessary checks, but the maps are massive can be anything from 10x10 to 200x200 tiles and the only thing slowing down the game significantly is the AI, I've also tried to implement a distance based solution where the creeps Idle until i am in a certain range but that still slows down the game a lot because a lot of creeps are spawned. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: can you calculate some major paths earlier, and during the game, just calculate access to them?

Comment: so use more of a node based approach?where the enemy moves to a node on the map and then if player is in range then apply A*?

Comment: yes, that should speed your application

Comment: How often do you compute paths ? It is usually not necessary to recompute them at each logic tick, you can let each agent recompute its path only once every second for example.

Comment: I recompute on each frame, wouldn't it create a more lagging effect if i recompute slower?

Comment: Agree with ARRG... spread out your usage of A*.  Do a couple of 'creeps' per frame, not all of them every frame.  At most, you probably only need to be calculating the path for a 'creep' every half a second (each 15-30 frames).  You can prioritize that too, based on the distance from the player.  If a 'creep' is far from the player, run A* once and start moving until the distance between them is smaller.  Something along those lines.

Comment: yeah after implementing it yesterday i saw a much bigger improvement than i expected, i've got a few ideas on how to improve it more at the moment but just delaying the usage already helped :D thanks for the input I appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numbers of ways of speeding up your code.

First - there are many modifications of the A* algorithm, which may be used, like:

- Hierarchical A*, which is often used method in games, where the map is analyzed on many resolution levels, from "general planning" to the "local path search" http://aigamedev.com/open/review/near-optimal-hierarchical-pathfinding/
- Jump Point Search A*, which dramaticaly speeds up A* for maps with lots of open spaces (like RPG games) http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/speed-up-a-star-pathfinding-with-the-jump-point-search-algorithm/

Other modifications can be more application specific, if your creeps are searching a path to the player (there is **one** goal for all creeps), then you can change your search to one of following algorithms:

- calculate distance **from** player to each point in the map using Dijkstra algorithm, for 200x200 it will be very quick (40,000 vertices with `O(nlgn)` algorithm), and simply move your creep to any adjacent point with less distance to player then current one
- run A* search from the player to any creep (with lowest id for example), once the path is found - change aim to the next creep but **do not** reset the algorithm itself, let if use already computed paths and distances (as they are already optimal paths from player), obviously - if during execution you encounter another creep then your goal - you simply record it (found path is optimal).

Another possible modification, which can be applied if your map is somehow specific (contains doors/entrances to some parts of it) is to place triggers, which "enable" creeps AI. This is `O(1)` solution, but requires a specific type of map.

And one final idea would be to implement some suboptimal solutions, by for example:

- First, calculate A* for each creep
- If the distance to the player is smaller then some threshold value `T`, then in next iteration - recalculate your path, so there is no lag
- otherwise - follow your path for at least 10-50 iterations before another path search

There are countless more optimizations, but we would need more details regarding your game as well as time you wish to spend on those optimizations.

Comment: Looking at the Jump Point Search A* seems to be exactly what I am looking for, as for the game its a RPG/Shooter survival game where the world can be any size and consist of small rooms, doors triggers, lights etc the creeps spawn randomly at set intervals and can decide either to chase down the player or to flock together with other creeps to form herds based on their distance from the player. Im doing the game in my spare time and the AI optimizations are some of the last things I have to do with the engine so i am trying to get it as good as I can :D Thanks for everyone's input, helps alot